# PHP interpreter on file upload

Tags: php, file, nginx, file-upload, interpreter

On uploading files to PHP (for example working on nginx) I have to wait until file was uploaded. If I have large file (like 20MB) and slow internet connection, request can take some time to proceed. Does file upload occupy PHP interpreter in that time, or is file being uploaded firstly to web server, and than handled to PHP script (PHP interpreter occupied only for the time of "logical execution" after receiving the file)?

Comment: When I last checked, the web server calls the interpreter (php) only when the file is completely uploaded with the relevant info structures in Php interface filled. I mostly tried to help the web server to not be to busy waiting while the upload was inprogress ;-)